# Encountering "Encrypted data invalid" error while using message.click() method in Telethon

Tags: python, telethon

I'm developing a app using Telethon, and I'm using the message.click() method to click on buttons in messages. However, I'm encountering an "Encrypted data invalid" error when using this method. I'm unable to determine the source of my problem and I need help on how to resolve it.

Below, I'm sharing the code snippet I'm using:

```py
async def send_response(self, chat_id, message_id, button_data, button_text):
    try:
        message = await self.client.get_messages(chat_id, ids=message_id)
        if button_data:
            await message.click(data=button_data)
        else:
            await message.click(text=button_text)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        return False
```

Here is the error message I'm encountering:

> Encrypted data invalid (caused by GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest)

Any help or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: better show full error message. You could also run without `try/except` to see full error message. You may also need to change `logging` setting because telethon may catch errors to keep working.